# Uploading Values of Array of Objects in (key, value) Into DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/3bqxy2np/) and let me know how I can securely load the `values` of an array of objects into a `DataTable`. Basically what I have is a dataset in this format

```
var dataSet = {
    1: {
        AnnualFirmEnergy: "91.2335550",
        CostOfEnergy: "183.835765",
        CostPerYear: "16771990.38",
        Footprint: "182.3077770",
        InstalledCapacity: "31.320802",
        Penstock: "5000.000000",
    },
    2: {
        AnnualFirmEnergy: "91.2335550",
        CostOfEnergy: "183.835765",
        CostPerYear: "16771990.38",
        Footprint: "182.3077770",
        InstalledCapacity: "31.320802",
        Penstock: "5000.000000",
    },
    3: {
        AnnualFirmEnergy: "91.2335550",
        CostOfEnergy: "183.835765",
        CostPerYear: "16771990.38",
        Footprint: "182.3077770",
        InstalledCapacity: "31.320802",
        Penstock: "5000.000000",
    }
}
```

and I want to load only the values of the objects into the table,  like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Position" },
            { title: "Office" },
            { title: "Extn." },
            { title: "Start date" },
            { title: "Salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You need to pre-process your data before passing to jQuery DataTables. Consider using the code below:

```js
function preprocData(dataIn){
   var dataOut = [];
   for(id in dataIn){
      if(dataIn.hasOwnProperty(id)){         
         dataOut.push(dataIn[id]);
         dataOut[dataOut.length - 1].Id = id;
      }
   }
   return dataOut;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: preprocData(dataSet),
        columns: [
            { data: "Id", title: "Id" },
            { data: "AnnualFirmEnergy", title: "AnnualFirmEnergy" },
            { data: "CostOfEnergy", title: "CostOfEnergy" },
            { data: "CostPerYear", title: "CostPerYear" },
            { data: "Footprint", title: "Footprint" },
            { data: "InstalledCapacity", title: "InstalledCapacity" },
            { data: "Penstock", title: "Penstock" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3bqxy2np/2/) for code and demonstration.